# BizFX needs storefront with name matching ShopName configuration value

Tags: sitecore-commerce

After renaming the ShopName in my BizFX `config.json` file, BizFX failed to load. Inspecting the network tab in my browser, I found that `GetNavigationView()` and `GetLanguagesView()` calls fail with the error message

```
{
  "Code":"Error",
  "Text":"Shop 'newShopName' does not exist.",
  "CommerceTermKey":"InvalidShop"
}
```

From digging through logs I found that BizFX is looking for a storefront with a name matching the ShopName configuration value.

What does BizFX use this storefront configuration for and is it possible to have multiple storefronts under a BizFX site?

Answer (score 0):

Business tools mainly deal with commerce environments (HabitatShop, HabitatAuthoring, etc). The `Shopname` configured in `config.json` is for the authoring environment and is passed in as a header to authoring. It is for getting the commerce terms (messages) from Storefront Control Panel in Sitecore.

I don't really see a need for Business Tools using a different shopname.

So you can change the config.json shopname to match the Storefront Control Panel shopname and configure authoring to have multiple commerce environments in `global.json`, add environments, and bootstrap. It will then show new environments in the business tools.

Answer (score 0):

Bizfx uses the storefront configuration to load the authoring or shops environment. It is possible to have multiple storefronts under storefront control panel but as per my experience you can connect to one storefront at a time by specifying its details in config.json for bizfx.